# Error 404 while linking Php/Html pages

Tags: php, html

I am linking my navigation bar list items to includes folder page with  href Attribute

```
<li><a href="/opt/lampp/htdocs/FoundationFlex/admin/includes/brands.php">Brands</a></li>
```

I have tried copying full path 
I have tried setting permission on htdocs to 777 but still not working.

[My code and folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06h3Z.jpg)

I am using new Ubuntu machine (16.04) with XAmp

This is my error :

> Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

Comment: Please describe your issue in more detail along with the code which you've added into the href.

Comment: Error 404 means that the page could not be found under this link. Ergo your link must either be wrong or the file is not at the position you're linking to. Please share your full file structure / the structure of your folder so we can take a look at it

Comment: you need to write href tags value like this `href="http://localhost/your_project_dire/your_include_folder_path/your_navigation_path/filename.php"` this will work with core php, if any framework then use the framework documentation. Directorates should be in sense like `your_project_dire >>>   your_include_folder_path >>> your_navigation_path >>> filename.php.
In case any directory is outside from above sequence then use `href="http://localhost/your_project_dire/your_include_folder_path/your_navigation_path/../filename.php"` here `../` is to select one back directory

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/06h3Z.jpg This is my code and folder structure. Project is located inside /opt/lampp/htdocs/FoundationFlex

Comment: Whatever problem you are trying to solve, **giving everyone write access to system resources is not the way to get there.** You should revert the permissions to something sane *(read* access for everyone should be fine, `chmod 755` for directories and `chmod 644` for files) but **`chmod 777` is wrong and a *serious security problem*** and you should revert this change ASAP.

Comment: Thank you !
Yes I have changed it back to 755 the moment I realized it is not the issue

Comment: You need to learn the difference between file system paths, and URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your code with this `<li><a href="http://localhost/FoundationFlex/admin/includes/brands.php">Brands</a></li>` or `<li><a href="FoundationFlex/admin/includes/brands.php">Brands</a></li>`

the problem in your href link is that you are giving a file path in browser, which correct but not executable nor a website url so it will always throw a 404 error which means the web page doesn't exits.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting wrong path

This is your site url

```
http://localhost/FoundationFlex/
```

and this is your file path

```
<a href="/admin/includes/brand.php">Brand</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to link using PATH on server, use URL instead and make sure this file is accessible from browser

```
<li><a href="http://example.com/FoundationFlex/admin/includes/brands.php">Brands</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the full file system path of the file. But you must enter a relative path to your webservers root folder (htdocs).

So if you call your page with http://localhost/ then in your case your webserver root folder seems to be /opt/lampp/htdocs/. Linking the file brands.php in a html link will look like this (relative):

```
<a href="FoundationFlex/admin/includes/brands.php">Brands</a>
```

or absolute

```
<a href="/FoundationFlex/admin/includes/brands.php">Brands</a>
```

or (but this one should have the same result ase the one above:

```
<a href="http://localhost/FoundationFlex/admin/includes/brands.php">Brands</a>
```

These links can help you:

https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Answer (score 0):

If `/opt/lampp/htdocs/FoundationFlex` is your servers DocumentRoot you can just

```
<a href="/admin/includes/brand.php">Brand</a>
```